# How add more sidebars to site in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new in Wordpress so if my question simple is I apologize. So
I want to add second sidebar to my page. I added one to my page, but when i try to add the second i have the same sidebar as in the first.

How can i add two or more sidebar in wordpress?

I inserted some examples of my code. File **function.php**

```
register_sidebar(
array(
    'name' => 'Program 1',
    'id' => 'program_1',
    'description' => 'module',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="left-sidebar"><ul class="subnav">',
    'after_widget' => '</ul></div>',
    'before_title' => '<div style="display:none !important;">',
    'after_title' => '</div>',
    'class' => 'subnav'
)
```

);

```
register_sidebar(
array(
    'name' => 'Program 2',
    'id' => 'program_2',
    'description' => 'Si li ha',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="left-sidebar"><ul class="subnav">',
    'after_widget' => '</ul></div>',
    'before_title' => '<div style="display:none !important;">',
    'after_title' => '</div>',
    'class' => 'subnav'
)
```

);

File **sidebar.php** . I thnik probably the solution is in this file. But how to include both sidebars?

```
<?php if(!dynamic_sidebar('program_1')): ?>
<div class="widget">
    <h2>Programs</h2>
</div>
```

Thanks more!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to create a new page template by copying 'page.php' to 'page-sidebar2.php' and to add the following at the top of the page

```
<?php
    /*
      Template name: Page with Sidebar 2
    */
?>
```

In this new template you search for `get_sidebar()` and edit this to `get_sidebar('sidebar2')`.

Then as the last step you duplicate sidebar.php to sidebar-sidebar2.php and modify

`<?php if(!dynamic_sidebar('program_1')): ?>`

to

`<?php if(!dynamic_sidebar('program_2')): ?>`

Save all the files and create a new page with the new available template (choose it from the right). It should use the new created sidebar instead of the old one.

Comment: do you sure that your way is right? i made but something wrong. Does it mean wordpress can automatically read all files sidebar.*.php?

Comment: well, i did as you said, but have nothing nothing. Would you tell me where can be my error

Comment: Not filename.*.php, you have to use a -. So page-sidebar.php en sidebar-sidebar2.php. I'm sure it works, because it's the way to go. http://codex.wordpress.org/Templates

Comment: thanks i have already resolved it and your advise was useful. and one moment by  .* ( dot and *) i meant regular expression.